# Connecting RC controller to Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, dji-sdk

I've been using the SDK in Android Studio and was wondering if it's possible to connect the RC Controller (either from Mavic 2 Zoom or the Matrice 210 RTK) to the laptop and have the emulator communicate with the controller rather than using a physical phone for development/testing?

If the SDK is not possible, would any of the off-the-shelf apps from DJI be able to run on an emulator?

If so, are there better device emulators that work best with DJI?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've found that the emulators lack the capabilities to process the USB data fast thought enough to connect to aircraft.   You really must use a real Android device.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to connect the RC directly to the emulator, but you could use the bridge app in addition to the emulator.

https://github.com/dji-sdk/Android-Bridge-App